# How to remove post redirects

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, wp-redirect

I recently installed a plugin called "Q and A FAQ and Knowledge Base for WordPress"

Turns out it was lacking in the features I needed so I trashed every faq I had created and then deactivated the plugin.

I have since gone and created a post with the same name/url (i.e. /faqs) BUT when I access the /faqs URL is displays all the faq posts that I have previously deleted?

How can I make sure that nothing to do with faqs still shows up?  How can I permanently remove the redirect to /faqs which displays the old faqs and make it show my new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - It had also created a "Page" which was still using the /faqs slug.